# How can I stop a long running BigQuery job?

Tags: google-bigquery

I've kicked off a query that is taking way too long b/c I used a sort on a non-aggregated query.

Is there a way to stop a long running job ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like one of the BigQuery backend shards died while this job was running -- this should be extremely rare. There isn't a way to stop a query that is currently running, but I'm investigating why it took us an hour to figure out there was a problem.